# Get the name and extension of selected file in active window by delphi

Tags: delphi

I want to get and show the name and extension of selected file in explorer by delphi7.

I use below code for show caption of active window but i need selected file name in active window.

```
function ActiveCaption: string;

var
  Handle: THandle;
  Len: LongInt;
  Title: string;

begin
  Result := '';
  Handle := GetForegroundWindow;
  if Handle <> 0 then
  begin
    Len := GetWindowTextLength(Handle) + 1;
    SetLength(Title, Len);
    GetWindowText(Handle, PChar(Title), Len);
    ActiveCaption := TrimRight(Title);
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Label1.Caption := ActiveCaption;
end;
```

Comment: Use the shell API rather than hacking at the implementation details. Also, read your question and see how poorly the formatting is. Then edit it and read the help on how to format. Then fix the formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I know of is to use the Active-X IShellWindows and IWebBrowser Interfaces to to that.

First, you have to import the "Microsoft Internet Controls" Active-X (via the Component Menu). By that you will get a unit called "SHDocVW_TLB". Put this unit and the ActiveX unit in your uses clause.

Than you can use the following two functions to retrieve the selected file from the window handle provided:

The first function does a rough test if the given handle belongs to an explorer window

```
function isexplorerwindow(exwnd: hwnd): boolean;
var
  p: array[0..max_path] of Char;
begin
  GetClassName(exwnd, p, SizeOf(p));
  result := ((strcomp(p, 'CabinetWClass') = 0) or (strcomp(p, 'ExploreWClass') = 0));
end;
```

And the second function retrieves the name of the nth selected file:

```
function getexplorerselectedfile(exwnd: hwnd; nr: integer): string;
var
  pvShell: IShellWindows;
  pvWeb2: IWebBrowser2;
  ovIE: OleVariant;
  psp: IServiceProvider;
  psb: IShellBrowser;
  isw: IShellView;
  ido: IDataObject;
  FmtEtc: TFormatEtc;
  Medium: TStgMedium;
  dwcount: integer;
  n: integer;
  p: array[0..max_path] of Char;
  s: string;
  found: boolean;
begin
  found := false;
  result := '';
  s :='';
  try
    pvShell := CoShellWindows.Create;
    for dwcount := 0 to Pred(pvShell.count) do
    begin
      ovIE := pvShell.Item(dwcount);
      if (ovIE.hwnd = exwnd) or ((exwnd = 0) and isexplorerwindow(ovIE.hwnd)) then
      begin
        found := true;
        if (IDispatch(ovIE).QueryInterface(IWebBrowser2, pvWeb2) = S_OK) then
        begin
          psp := (pvWeb2 as IServiceProvider);
          psp.QueryService(IID_IShellBrowser, IID_IShellBrowser, psb);
          psb.QueryActiveShellView(isw);
          if isw.GetItemObject(SVGIO_SELECTION, IDataObject, pointer(ido)) = S_OK then
          begin
            try
              FmtEtc.cfFormat := CF_HDROP;
              FmtEtc.ptd := nil;
              FmtEtc.dwAspect := DVASPECT_CONTENT;
              FmtEtc.lindex := -1;
              FmtEtc.tymed := TYMED_HGLOBAL;
              ido.GetData(FmtEtc, Medium);
              GlobalLock(Medium.hGlobal);
              try
                n := DragQueryFile(Medium.hGlobal, $FFFFFFFF, nil, 0);
                if nr < n then
                begin
                  DragQueryFile(Medium.hGlobal, nr, p, max_path);
                  s := strpas(p);
                end;
              finally
                DragFinish(Medium.hGlobal);
                GlobalUnLock(Medium.hGlobal);
              end;
            finally
              ReleaseStgMedium(Medium);
            end;
          end;
          pvWeb2 := nil;
        end;
      end;
      ovIE := Unassigned;
      if found then
        break;
    end;
    pvShell := nil;
  finally
    result := s;
  end;
end;
```

To test this code create a new project and place a button and a memo on the form.

Add the following units to the uses clause:

```
USES SHDocVW_TLB, ShlObj, activex, shellapi;
```

And add this code to the button event handler:

```
PROCEDURE TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
VAR
  wnd, exwnd: hwnd;
  n: integer;
  s: STRING;
BEGIN
  exwnd := 0;
  wnd := getwindow(getdesktopwindow, gw_child);
  REPEAT
    IF isexplorerwindow(wnd) THEN
    BEGIN
      exwnd := wnd;
      break;
    END;
    wnd := getwindow(wnd, gw_hwndnext);
  UNTIL (wnd = 0) OR (exwnd <> 0);
  IF exwnd <> 0 THEN
  BEGIN
    n := 0;
    REPEAT
      s := getexplorerselectedfile(exwnd, n);
      memo1.Lines.Add(s);
      inc(n);
    UNTIL s = '';
  END;
END;
```

If you press the button, the memo will contain the selected files of the first open explorer window it finds. Of course you should have an explorer window open with at least one file selected.

Comment: I mean windows explorer  not internet explorer

Comment: I know. And if you would try, you would discover that this is for Windows Explorer. The Windows Explorer uses the IWebBrowser2 interface, too.

Comment: See for example here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/gg314982%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: thanks.i use delphi 7 and it seems there is some error.there is no IShellWindows in delphi 7 and cause error

Comment: Should be defined in the ShlObj unit. Include this to the uses clause. I am however not sure whether this is already available in Delphi 7, but I think so.

Comment: i installed delphi xe 10.2 tokyo but i cant run your above code.can you send complete code?or guide how can i run it?

Comment: Can you tell me what problem do you have? Does it compile, but not run or even not compile? Do you have imported the "Microsoft Internet Controls" Active-X?

Comment: yes,i imported activex but it seems some thing is missing in your  code .you sent two functions "isexplorerwindow" and "getexplorerselectedfile" but there is no code for calling these function in main body of project.if possible please send all code(include function and main body code)thanks

Comment: I can't believe I should write your program. I added an instruction to my answer above and code how to call the function. Tested just now. It works if you follow the instructions.

Comment: sorry.i didnt find out you changed the code.it worked.but there is some problem.in memo there is full address of selected file and i just want file name + extension also i want program show selected file  every 1 second(no need for pressing buttom).thanks

Comment: Well than use a timer to get the path instead of the button and use the according delphi functions to split up file path. The functions are: "extractfilename", "extractfilepath" or "extractfileext". Find info about these functions in the delphi help. This is however a different issue. Open a new question in this case. The original question should be solved and accepted by this answer, now.